# ng-app not necessary in some cases?

Tags: angularjs

While attempting to build an RSS feed parser I found the below example. It does not use the `ng-app` directive anywhere. However, a controller is being used that is attached to the declared module `RSSFeedApp`.

How is this possible? My understanding was that we always needed to declare `ng-app` or perform a `bootstrap` to have AngularJS work.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mahbub/b8Wcz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that it does use the `ng-app` directive. In the JSFiddle left panel, click on Fiddle Options and look at the body tag textbox. It is declared as:

```
<body ng-app="RSSFeedApp">
```

Comment: Thanks. Giving you the correct answer since you squeaked it in first.

Answer (score 2):

In the fiddle options, it's specified on the  tag:

```
<body ng-app="RSSFeedApp">
```

You're not crazy, ng-app or bootstrap is always required.